# POST Content-Length even after updating php.ini

Tags: php

I changed both `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to `128M`. The video I'm trying to upload is only 40MB and shouldn't be causing any issues. If it's any help I'm using MAMP Pro with PHP 5.5.10. I've searched a bunch of places and nothing seems to solve it. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: have you restart your server after changing upload_max_filesize ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAMP Dynamically creates the `php.ini` file each time it's run. Changing the file in the physical directory will have no effect on how PHP works. In order to change the `php.ini` in MAMP Pro you must go to `file > Edit Template > PHP > php.ini`. After changing this file you should restart MAMP and your changes should work.